# Compare two branches in git from outside of the repo

Tags: git, branch, diff

If I clone my git repository, comparing two branches is simple.

```
git clone $REPOURL repodir
cd repodir
git diff branch1..branch2
```

I'd like to be able to do this using the URL without cloning the repository.
This would be useful for reviewing changes in someone else's repository without having to clone it first.

I've seen various vague examples posted, but nothing worked in my git version: 2.14.1

Reading through the git diff documentation didn't really lead me to a working example either (yet), so posting here to speed up the process of figuring out the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: What url are you talking about?

Comment: The URL to the git repository on a git server.

Comment: Diff operates locally. Unless the server provides a means to do this outside of Git, I cannot think of a way it would be possible.

Comment: Would you be able to show one of the 'vague examples' you mention?

Answer (score 0):

The way Git works is really to download all the revisions first, and then most commands run locally. This is how Git runs so fast for most operations. `diff` is one of them, it doesn't download anything.

This doesn't mean you have to "clone": you can use an existing clone and fetch your coworker's branch into it. For example:

```
git remote add <url> my-friend
git fetch my-friend
git diff my-friend/branch1 my-friend/branch2
```

Alternatively, depending on the hosting you're using, the server may be able to let you compare branches from its web interface. For example, on GitHub, this is `https://github.com/<organisation>/<project>/compare/<branch1>...<branch2>`, like this: https://github.com/git/git/compare/master...next